# ProgressDialog is not dismissing in TabLayout in android

Tags: java, android, progressdialog

I am working with ProgressDialog on calling of webservice methods.  but issue i am facing is that in my tablayout my 3 to 4 webservices run at a time and every method is starting its own dialog. but on Service result ProgressDialog is not dismissing and running continuously. I am using this code to dismiss ProgressDialog.

**Please Note that This is very Big project and I am using these two method all over the Project**

- **For initializing from util class**

```html
public static void showDialog(Context context){
        progressBar= ProgressDialog.show(context, "Loading...", "Please wait few seconds...", false, true);

    }
```

- **For Dismissing From Util class**

```html
public static void hideDialog(Context context){
        progressBar.dismiss();
    }
```

Please guys help me to find the solution